# How to display Vaadin grid with nested objects?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I am having trouble with binding properties and displaying the grid in Vaadin 23

```
class SampleUser
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @Email
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    private String occupation;
    private boolean important;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    Department department;
```

```
class Department
    private String building;
    private String floor;
    private String room;
    private String division;
    private String department;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "email")
    SampleUser user;
```

displaying grid

```
grid.addColumn(SampleUser::getFirstName).setHeader("First Name").setAutoWidth(true).setSortable(true);
grid.addColumn(SampleUser::getLastName).setHeader("Last Name").setAutoWidth(true).setSortable(true);
grid.addColumn(SampleUser::getEmail).setHeader("Email").setAutoWidth(true).setSortable(true);
grid.addColumn(SampleUser::getPhone).setHeader("Phone").setAutoWidth(true).setSortable(true);
grid.addColumn(SampleUser::getDateOfBirth).setHeader("Date Of Birth").setAutoWidth(true).setSortable(true);
grid.addColumn(SampleUser::getOccupation).setHeader("Occupation").setAutoWidth(true).setSortable(true);
```

How to display the department property in SampleUser?

I tried with this but getting
"There was an exception while trying to navigate to '' with the root cause 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: Property type 'com.example.application.data.entity.Department' doesn't match the field type 'java.lang.String'. Binding should be configured manually using converter.'"

```
grid.addColumn(department -> department.getDepartment().getDepartment() == null ? "" : department.getDepartment().getDepartment()).setHeader("Department").setAutoWidth(true).setSortable(true);
```

Comment: _field_ type?  This more looks like an error with binding a form? Check
the full stacktrace and try to see where it originates from your
classes.  Random side note: depending on the ORM you are using, you may
be building up a N+1 problem here. For full control, it's most efficient
to do the join yourself.

Comment: I don't know how to bind the department field in SampleUser class. I successfully display the other fields.

Comment: Is this the edit feature from the pro-grid? I don't see how the grid code relates to the field error?

Comment: I have no idea, i am new to Vaadin. I read a lot of sources for displaying grid but no one was with nested objects.

Comment: Well then remove your department code from the grid setup and see if it persists

Comment: Yes, when i remove department it works and displays data, but i need to display department as well. Is this possible?

Comment: Ok, then the error is just confusing. Thanks for verifying

Comment: As @cfrick said you should use a DTO in the grid. But the error message cannot be from the grid but from the form. How did you create the form?

Comment: This is my class for displaying grid https://pastebin.com/0VCYYrTt

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
private TextField department;
```

As you use bindInstanceFields of the Binder it tries to bind a property of type String with the name department. For the department you will need a Select or ComboBox.

To display the department in the Grid this is the correct code:

```
grid.addColumn(samplePerson -> samplePerson.getDepartment().getDepartment() == null 
                               ? "" : department.getDepartment().getDepartment())
              .setHeader("Department").setAutoWidth(true).setSortable(true);
```